# Guard: How to run only certain group by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I've defined 3 groups in my `Guardfile`, and I know I can use the `-g` parameter to run only the given groups.

But since I mostly want to run Guard with two specific groups: Is it possible to run these groups by default, without the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Guard, but some workaround comes to mind:

Create an alias that evaluates only a specific group:

`$ alias guard=guard -g default`

Now only the group `default` group is used, but you can overwrite it:

`$ guard -g other`

You can also split your `Guardfile`, having your common plugins in it and extract the seldom used into another file, which you can use:

`$ guard -G Otherfile`

Since I also have the need for a better group management, I've planned to extend Guard to allow you to define the default groups in your `Guardfile` and add/remove more groups from the list of active groups from within the interactor.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to assign a scope to your **Guardfile**:

> scope groups: [:specs, :rake]

With that you are specifying the default set of groups to run. In this example group "rake" and "specs"